# Split Comma Separated Names with PHP

Tags: php

I have names in the form of **Lastname, Firstname**. In my database I have a different field for both the first and last.

I would like to use PHP to read everything before the comma as the lastname and everything after the comma as the firstname. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list($Lastname,$Firstname) = explode(",",$Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   <?php 
        $names = explode( "," , $allNames);
       // $names[0] and names[1] are first and last names
      ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

with the explode function.

```
<?php 
list($lastname, $firstname) = explode(',','Lastname, Firstname',2);
echo $firstname.' '.$lastname;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll use `list()`;

```
while( list($fname,$lname) = explode(", ", $db->fetch() ) ) {
   echo $lname . " " . $fname . "<br />";
}
```

Without `list()` and assining an array;

```
$name = explode( ", ", $db->fetch()->nameField );
// may be you want to do something with that array
// do something
// echoing
foreach( $name as $fname=>$lname ) {
    echo $lname . " " . $fname . "<br />"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As nobody has mentioned it yet, to expressly meet the question requirements, you'll need to use the third parameter to `explode()`

```
list($lastname, $firstname) = explode(',', $name, 2);
```