# Split name string using php

Tags: php, string, split, phpmyadmin

How do you split a string using php?

For example, I have a table where a column is a full name of a person.

```
wholename
-------------
Smith, John B.
Pascal, Mary Anne A.
Dela Cruz, James Mark
```

Then I want to split it into three sections `lastname`, `firstname`, `middleinital`

```
lastname        firstname       middleinitial
----------      ----------      ----------      
Smith           John            B.
Pascal          Mary Anne       A.
Dela Cruz       James Mark
```

Then I want to output it into a site. So far, the code I have only stores the whole name in a session string.

Answer (score 0):

Here have a answer to [Split first and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221937/split-comma-separated-names-with-php).

Now with variable `$firstName`, you get middle name where have dot at first name.

```
if(strpos($nome, "."))
{
    $middlename = substr($firstname, strrpos($firstname, " "));
    $firstname = substr($firstname, 0, strrpos($firstname, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this format, you can do it using this regular expression:

```
$regex = '/(?P<lastname>[a-zA-Z ]+)\,\s(?P<firstname>[a-zA-Z ]+)(\s(?P<middleinitial>\w\.)|$)/';
$wholenames = ['Smith, John B.', 'Pascal, Mary Anne A.', 'Dela Cruz, James Mark'];
foreach ($wholenames as $wholename) {
    preg_match($regex, $wholename, $matches);
    var_dump($matches['lastname']);
    var_dump($matches['firstname']);
    var_dump($matches['middleinitial']);
    echo "-------------\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
string(5) "Smith"
string(4) "John"
string(2) "B."
-------------
string(6) "Pascal"
string(9) "Mary Anne"
string(2) "A."
-------------
string(9) "Dela Cruz"
string(10) "James Mark"
NULL
-------------
```